# Equivalent of public static final fields in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm learning Scala, and I can't figure out how to best express this simple Java class in Scala:

```
public class Color {
  public static final Color BLACK = new Color(0, 0, 0);
  public static final Color WHITE = new Color(255, 255, 255);     
  public static final Color GREEN = new Color(0, 0, 255);

  private final int red;
  private final int blue;
  private final int green;

  public Color(int red, int blue, int green) {
    this.red = red;
    this.blue = blue;
    this.green = green;
  }

  // getters, et cetera
}
```

The best I have is the following:

```
class Color(val red: Int, val blue: Int, val green: Int)
object BLACK extends Color(0, 0, 0)
object WHITE extends Color(255, 255, 255)
object GREEN extends Color(0, 0, 255)
```

But I lose the advantages of having BLACK, WHITE, and GREEN being tied to the Color namespace.

Answer (score 17):

```
case class Color(red: Int, blue: Int, green: Int)

object Color {
  val BLACK = Color(0, 0, 0)
  val WHITE = Color(255, 255, 255)
  val GREEN = Color(0, 0, 255)
}
```

Comment: As an aside note, the Scala convention is to use PascalCase for constants, such as `Black`.

Answer (score 13):

You could just put the specific colors into the companion object:

```
class Color(val red: Int, val blue: Int, val green: Int)
object Color {
  object BLACK extends Color(0, 0, 0)
  object WHITE extends Color(255, 255, 255)
  object GREEN extends Color(0, 0, 255)
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, you could have vals within the companion object:

```
class Color(val red: Int, val blue: Int, val green: Int)
object Color {
  val BLACK = new Color(0, 0, 0)
  val WHITE = new Color(255, 255, 255)
  val GREEN = new Color(0, 0, 255)
}
```

You could make them lazy to defer instantiation until they are used:

```
class Color(val red: Int, val blue: Int, val green: Int)
object Color {
  lazy val BLACK = new Color(0, 0, 0)
  lazy val WHITE = new Color(255, 255, 255)
  lazy val GREEN = new Color(0, 0, 255)
}
```

Going back the original solution, you could prevent extension of the class (simulating "final" by making the Color class sealed:

```
sealed class Color(val red: Int, val blue: Int, val green: Int)
object Color {
  object BLACK extends Color(0, 0, 0)
  object WHITE extends Color(255, 255, 255)
  object GREEN extends Color(0, 0, 255)
}
```

Comment: (I'm not a Scala person. Does that work for "final" classes?)

Comment: You cannot extends a final class, but you could make it "sealed" so that it cannot be extended outside of the current compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

sealed allows object extensions with the same physical file..not in different file. sealed is more close to package scope than the final.